# Django - Help restoring accidentlally deleted user

Tags: django

Say I accidentally deleted a django.contrib.auth.models.User entry in django, where it cascade deleted all the rows that were affected.

What would I have to do to restore that user from a backup?

I'm assuming the steps would be:

1. Load the backup on a separate machine
2. Identify the rows affected by a cascade delete of an Auth User
3. Copy those rows from the backup on the separate machine to the affected machine

What tools/scripts can I use for steps 2 and 3? Do I need to write my own or are there built in utilities that may help?

Answer (score 2):

Restore the database and enter `/admin/`. Go to `User` model and try deleting same user. Admin should ask you if you are certain and display you information which other objects will get deleted as of cascade. This is what you can get easily and for free in **Django**.

Comment: Agreed, but was looking for a way to get that same information in the shell?

Comment: I have no idea, if there is similar capability for shell.

Answer (score 2):

The admin app uses the `get_deleted_objects` function in [`django.contrib.admin.util`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/util.py) to find the related objects.

In the shell, you could import this function. However it will take a bit of work to understand the required arguments. It might be simpler to use the admin website as @gruszczy suggests in his answer.